# Real-time Video capturing c++ lib

Tags: c++, rtsp

Can you advice me  any lib, which can help me to capture rtsp stream from ip camers. I have already used ffmpeg and openCV for this task, but ffmpeg has problems with working with AXIS IP-cameras, and openCV can't give me compressed data befor decompressing it (but i have to keep them cmpressed in archive). I develop on windows and Qt, if there are some ready binary lib files, it will be great, becouse, lots of libs if so complicated to build. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try your hand with the Red5 server.You will get what you want.Cheers

Read more at: http://red5wiki.com/wiki/SteamStream